# Could not find a method View error

Tags: java, android

I'm a new to android and java but i don't understand to how to implement this method without it being an error when i click on the button in the app.
this is the code

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    public TextView theQuestion;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        theQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);

    }//end of onCreate


    public void action(View theQuestion){
        theQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void antiAction(View theQuestion){
        theQuestion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}//the end
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:onClick="action"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Go"
    android:id="@+id/button1" />
<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:onClick="antiAction"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="undo"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
```

and the xml code

please help me

Comment: where are your button ?

Comment: which error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

you have to way to button click ,,

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);

 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // Perform action on click
         }
     });
```

or go to res - layout - main.xml and in the button type this 
             android:onClick="button"

and take the name like this

```
public void button (view v ) 
{
type your code 
}
```

Comment: oh i forgot to mention that i had that in my xml                                        <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:onClick="action"

Answer (score 0):

Just Add `onClick="action"` on Button in layout XML.

There are Two type to perform onClick on Button
1. Add onClick="action" in layout XML
and then define action mathod in Java file

```
public void action(View view){
//where view define this button define in xml
// Perform action on click
}
```

2. After initializing the button add onCLickListener

   Button button =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button_id);

   ```
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                    }
                });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

none of the above worked, but this did
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }//end of onCreate


    public void action(View view){
        TextView theQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        theQuestion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

    public void antiAction(View view){
        TextView theQuestion = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        theQuestion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }


}//the end
```